# How to return Controller instead of View in RequestMapping in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have such scenario:

1. User opens form for adding new user.
2. User fills all the fields and press "Submit".
3. User must be redirected to the main page.

Main Page contains data from Data Base, so controller is required for this page for loading data.
For this moment controller of adding user looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNew(
    @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
    BindingResult result, SessionStatus status
) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "AddUser";
    } else {
        status.setComplete();
        return "MainPage";
    }
}
```

The problem is that in this case it opens MainPage.jsp without call corresponding controller, so MainPage is loaded without data from Data Base.
How to resolve this problem in a proper way?

Comment: Don't return the view, but the url of the controller which should render the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `"redirect:/main"` instead of `"MainPage"`, which will perform redirect to that mapping and it will go through the controller for the main page.

This assumes that your main page has request mapping set to `/main`. If it doesn't change it accordingly.

More information can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (search for redirect).